# Работа с пакетами в GoLang

Tags: golang, jetbrains

Начал изучать Go, работаю в GoLand.
Подошел к теме пакетов. Имеется проект с названием, создал там папку "somecode", создал 2 файла:

**factorial.go**:

```
package main

func factorial(n int) int 
{
    var result = 1
    for i:=1; i <= n; i++
    {
        result *= i
    }
    return result
}
```

и **main.go**:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(factorial(4))
    fmt.Println(factorial(5))
}
```

По уроку я вижу, что там тоже самое, обязательно `package` у файлов должен быть `package main`(хоть и IDE почему то автоматически ставит название пакета, как название моего пакета созданного в проекте.

Но при компиляции ошибка:

> # command-line-arguments
>
> somecode\main.go:6:14: undefined: factorial
>
> somecode\main.go:7:14: undefined: factorial

Почему? Как ее исправить?

Comment: EditConfiguration и там меняем File на Directory или Package, точно не помню какой из них.

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет явного импорта функционала factorial в файле main.go

В таком случае при компиляции через go build необходимо указать все файлы которые должны участвовать.

```
go build main.go factorial.go
```

Для большей информации:

```
go build --help
```

If the arguments are a list of .go files, build treats them as a list
of source files specifying a single package.

Answer (score 1):

У меня всё откомпилилось и заработало.
Использую MS VSC и Far
Пришлось отформатировать под стандарт
    package main

```
func factorial(n int) int {
    var result = 1
    for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
        result *= i
    }
    return result
}
```

Проверить в jetbrains не могу... 
Выглядит у вас вполне нормально, копайте в направлении jetbrains

А компилируете как? Попробуйте в командной строке

```
go build
```

Исключите вашу IDE